# Any way to get the no of days for a particular month?

Tags: asp.net, datetime

Actually i want to add name of months(Using C sharp) along with value in drop down list and i want to add it pro-grammatically.I have get the  method to display the name but for a particular month how to get the maximum number of days in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DaysInMonth** method.

```
int days=DateTime.DaysInMonth(2010,1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
  DateTime.DaysInMonth(1969, 11);
```

Comment: No aliostad a lot thanks to you as well u have also helped in the same way but the best can be given to only one otherwise i would have given to both of u he was given only because he has less reputation so he could be supported but if u feel i could change the best.

Comment: @jagdeep thanks. No I wasnt complaining, I left "My small token of gratitude :)" since @adatapost gave me an upvote so I returned it back. Happy that it is sorted.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Exec SpYearResult 2016 go Alter Procedure SpYearResult (@Year Int) as Begin Declare @Date dateTime; Declare @intValue int; declare @Test Table (Mon Varchar(50),DaysInMonth int) ; Set @intValue = 0 While @intValue <12 Begin SET @Date = Convert(Datetime,Convert(Varchar(4),@Year)+'-01-01') SET @date = DATEADD(mm,@intValue, @Date); INSERT INTO @Test SELECT DateName(mm,@date)+'-' +Convert(Varchar(4),@Year) as Mon, DAY(EOMONTH(@date)) AS DaysInMonth set @intValue = @intValue +1 End select * from @Test End
```